# How to handle multiple authentication strategies (jwt and anonymous) in rest api

Tags: rest, authorization, passport.js

I have a rest API that can be accessed by anonymous and authenticated users using jwt. Depending on if the user is authenticated, the API sends back slightly different data that are user-specific.

now how do I solve the following scenario: the user logs in and gets a token. some time passes and the token gets revoked/invalidated for some reason. the user doesn't know that yet and proceeds to request some data using that token. the question is, how does the API handle this request?

1- should the API return a 401 unauthorized response with no data

2- the API returns data for the user ignoring the expired token (as if he is not authenticated). But in this case how the user is informed that their token is not valid and that they got the response for anonymous users?

thanks in advance